# `helm upgrade --name` results in "Error: unknown flag: --name"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When running `helm upgrade --install --namespace $PROJECT_NAMESPACE --values values.yaml --name $SOME_NAME some/chart`.

I get `Error: unknown flag: --name`.

Is there no way to set the name of a chart you are targeting with `upgrade`? Is this only possible for `install`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was that no `--name` was needed.

The syntax for a Helm Upgrade is `"helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART]"`, so the "RELEASE" is the same as what would be the `--name` in a Helm Install.